# Can I use UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera somewhere in my view and not in my Navigation Bar?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, camera, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

So I can add a Camera button on my `UINavigationBar` with `UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera`.

I want to add the same button to somewhere in the center of my view (120, 160, 10, 10).

Can I use it like a UIButton and use that camera button or should I just create my custom button (which looks like the `UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera`) and use the same methods for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my suggestion is create UIButton with that camera image(which is in google image) then set the size as u needed then add it to ur view

because the UIBarButtonItem is Not inherited from UIView .it is from NSObject.

so u can't add them to ur View.

Comment: Roger. Yes, I can understand. I just wanted to double-check with StackOverflow. Thanks Madhu.